# Why is the value updated by using useState

Tags: reactjs, use-state

It's maybe a stupid question, but I still don't understand why is this working, I'm thinking about a while, so maybe someone can help me to get this through.

My logic: the value of the input is set to default value of the username useState hook (''). Okay, now when I type something, the changeUsername function will run (for me it is also strange, it should behave like when it is hardcoded, so the function shouldn't run at all), the username will be set to e.target.value which is ('') from the initial value of username, so why is the username updated?

I know it's a little messy what I try to explain, but I would expect that it works like when the value is hardcoded, like value='something'. Why can I still type in the input field when the value is set to ''?
I hope you get it what I want to ask and understand.

```
const [username, setUsername] = useState('');

const changeUsername = function (e) {
    setUsername(e.target.value);
};

<input type='text' id='username' value={username} onChange={changeUsername} />
```

Answer (score 4):

Because...

1. When the `<input>` invokes the `onChange` handler, it sends the *new* value as part of the event.  The "change", if you will.  (That's what's in `e.target.value`.)  This happens on every keystroke (every change).
2. `changeUsername` calls `setUsername` with that new value.
3. `setUsername` updates state and triggers a re-render.
4. In the re-render, `username` has this new state value and is set as the `value` of the `<input>`.

All of this happens *very* quickly (as in, faster than you can type the next character), and the re-render from React does not cause the element to lose focus.

So basically each keystroke updates the state and re-renders the entire component with the new state.

Comment: Okay thanks, but I still don't get it sorry :(.

Comment: By the hardcoded value, whatever I type, the username will always be what is in the value hardcoded `value='hardcode' the setUsername(e.target.value) will always return the 'hardcode'`. By the `value={username}` I expect the same. If I type something why is the e.target.value updated from '' to whatever I type? The value is the username, which is '', so how can the e.target.value updated, and the setUsename should be again '', becouse the e.target.value didn't change? That is what I don't understand. For me it's a devil circle.

Comment: @venndi: If you use a hard-coded value then it doesn't change because hard-coded values don't/can't change.  But if you use a *variable* then it can be set to a *new value*.  This is a fundamental concept of programming, in every programming language.  Even the name "variable" implies that its value can *vary*.  Calling `setUsername` with a new value results in `username` having this new value.  The mechanics of how specifically it does that are internal to the `useState` hook in `React`, but ultimately what it's doing is setting a value to a variable.

Comment: yes I understand that the hardcoded value doesn't change, it was just an example, maybe bad. For me when I set the `value` to the `username`, it's kinda hardcoded, so the value of the `value` is set to `''`, I know that isn't but yeah...hard to explain. So when I type a character in the input field, I don't get why is the `e.target.value` changed. The `setUsername` will be set to `e.target.value` which is the username, wich is `''`. Sorry maybe tomorrow I'll understand it. Thanks for your effort :)

Comment: @venndi `value` is not `e.target.value`. It sounds like that is your impression. `value` is whatever *you* want the input to be filled with when it is rendered to the DOM. `e.target.value` is based on how the *user* interacts with or changes that value.

Comment: @Brian Thompson: ohh thanks man, now I see it. Yes this was the trick for me. Even if I hard-code the value to 'abc' and if I type a 'd', the e.target.value will be 'abcd', of course the value will be always the 'abc'...thanks mate!

Answer (score 0):

I understand what you are trying to explain.
You are saying that when the value of the input is "exemple" it will not change what ever any function is in action.
The answer is easy and it is because you set the value=(useState value) and this value is always changing it is not fixed all the time,so the value of the input change when we change what is in the input.
Plus,When setState is run,the code is rerendered,for exemple,you add "r" to the input,initial state will be "r" instead of "".
Hope you get it.